# Using user input to search through an established dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I'm trying to get through my first semester of Python and am struggling. My dictionary is correct however, I cannot get what I want. I need the user to input a patient ID and then the program will display the ID with the name linked to it in the dictionary as the name is the value. Then if the user enters an ID that is not in the dictionary the computer tells them so. If they enter done the program says DONE! When numbers are entered the program needs to continue asking the question until done is typed. Here is was I have so far:

```
patientinfo = {}
lines = open('PatientsNames.txt')
lines.readline()

for line in lines:
    id=line[:8]
    if id not in patientinfo:
        endlastname = line.find(' ', 8)
        lastname = line[8:endlastname]
        firstname = line[endlastname+1:]
    patientinfo[id] = lastname + ', ' + firstname


answer = raw_input("Enter an ID ('done' to exit)")

try:
    if answer in patientinfo.keys():
        print answer, patientinfo(val)
except:
    if answer not in patientinfo.keys():
        print 'No patient with that ID'

else:
    if answer='done':
        print 'DONE!'
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question. What is the problem with your current code? What prevents you from progressing on it?

Comment: Specifically, can you give us an example of what `PatientNames.txt` looks like? It's hard to tell what might be wrong because your `for line in lines:` loop is very dependent on the structure of the `PatientNames.txt` file.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but unsure why your class is using Python 2 since support for it will it [is quickly dying](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3365221/python-2-end-of-life-how-to-survive-the-end-of-python-2.html)

Comment: @DarrylG: I can answer this since I'm in academic computer science. Many professors have written a curriculum and syllabus based on Python2 and are reluctant to refactor the course because of the work required. For science majors, many of their tools are in Python2 anyways (and are unlikely to be ported), so it makes sense to teach them Python2. In this case, I'd assume the course is being taught in Python2 and leave it at that.

Comment: Is it safe to say that there's a new line between each patient? (ie "B7E9FC4C Nieves Taylor\n")

Comment: Does Python 2 have context managers? If it does, you should use them. To check if a key is in a dictionary, you can just write `if my_key in my_dict`, no need for the `.keys()`. I’m also confused as to the structure and purpose of the try/except.

Comment: @MatthewCole Are there really that many libraries still on Python 2 only?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I feel like I can't answer that question fairly. I both teach my classes and develop prototypes for my manuscripts exclusively in Python3. I'm just echoing a response I frequently hear from more august faculty even though I don't agree with it.

Comment: The PatientName.txt is a list of names such as in Matthew Cole's question. The first half of my code works correctly. However, my issue comes in after the answer portion. I need python to prompt the user for an ID and then the program will tell the user if the ID was in the list and display the person's name, which is the value of the ID in the dictionary.

Comment: The try and except I was trying to use because if the user puts in an ID that is not in the list the program will tell them so and ask the question again. Then, lastly if the user types done the program states DONE! and ends the prompts.

Comment: @a2592432 The reason I asked about the data is because the goal is for anyone here to be able to run your program themselves. I don’t know at which state of development that last part was, but as it stands it certainly won’t behave that way.